# Getting a reference to a child Fragment after the parent Fragment has been recreated

Tags: android, android-fragments

Starting Android 4.2, Android supports [nested Fragments](http://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-4.2.html#NestedFragments). The doc doesn't give a lot of explanations regarding nested `Fragment` lifecycles but from experience, it appears their lifecycle is really similar to "regular" `Fragments`.

It looks like there is one big difference though: child `Fragments` are not restored when the parent `Fragment` `onCreate` method is called. As a consequence, it seems impossible to save/restore a reference to a particular `Fragment`:

- Using `getChildFragmentManager.findFragmentByTag(String)` always returns `null` in parent `Fragment` `onCreate(Bundle)` because `mActive` is `null`.
- Using `putFragment`/`getFragment` results in a `NullPointerException` because `getFragment` looks for the size of a null `mActive` `ArrayList`.

So, my question is quite simple. Is there a correct way to retrieve a reference to a child `Fragment` in the parent `Fragment` `onCreate` method?

Comment: Does `getChildFragmentManager().getFragments()` have a reference to the child fragment?

Comment: I only worked with the support libary implementation of nested fragments, but what I can say there is that nested fragments are recreated there and for dynamic situations you follow the usual "check if tagged fragment is in child fragment manager otherwise create the fragment anew" cycle. This worked quite well for me when I used child fragments as "workers" for example.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I don't think you can in `onCreate` as the view isn't constructed at that time. You can in `onViewCreated()` though. The logic I used is:

- Check if there is saved state in `onViewCreated()`, if there is, try to get the child fragment
- Then check if the child fragment is null, if it is, add it using the child fragment manager.

By "checking" I mean looking up the fragment by id. I guess by tag should work too.

AFAIK you can't get a child fragment *before* the view hierarchy is restored or created, but you could do the same at later time, for example in `onActivityCreated()`

Comment: I agree with this answer. For a headless fragment I use `onActivityCreated` hook to get access to child fragments.

Answer (score 1):

What about setRetainInstanceState(true) on your fragment?
Could it solve your problem? It solved some problems when I have ChildFragments in a Fragment. I only have to keep a reference to the childfragment in the fragment.

But I allways did that in onCreateView(). Not sure if it will work in onCreate()

Or do you mean something completely different?

Answer (score 1):

are u using FragmentPagerAdapter?
if not try FragmentPagerAdapter instead of FragmentStatePagerAdapter
I realised that have some bug when using FragmentStatePagerAdapter when i have 4 level nest.
Sorry my english is poor.

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    if (savedInstanceState != null) {
     mFragment1 = getFragmentManager().getFragment(savedInstanceState, STATE_Fragment1);
     mFragment2 = getFragmentManager().getFragment(savedInstanceState, STATE_Fragment2);
     mFragment3 = getFragmentManager().getFragment(savedInstanceState, STATE_Fragment3);
    } else {
     mFragment1 = SomeFragment.newInstance("param1");
     mFragment2 = SomeFragment.newInstance("param2");
     mFragment3 = SomeFragment.newInstance("param3");
    }
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    mMyPagerAdapter = new MyPagerAdapter(getChildFragmentManager(), mFragment1, mFragment2, mFragment3);
}

@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    if (mFragment1 != null) {
        getFragmentManager().putFragment(outState, STATE_Fragment1,
                mFragment1);
    }

    if (mFragment2 != null) {
        getFragmentManager().putFragment(outState, STATE_Fragment2,
                mFragment2);
    }

    if (mFragment3 != null) {
        getFragmentManager().putFragment(outState, STATE_Fragment3,
                mFragment3);
    }

    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
}
```