# Nested Fragments get view of parent fragment so I can anchor a control to it

Tags: c#, android, android-fragments, xamarin.android

I have a main activity, which hosts a viewpager for my fragments. When on a fragment in the pager, I have a child fragment that I am using for options/settings. I have two questions:

1. How do I get the view of the parent fragment from the child fragment? In other words, if a user clicks the options/settings, I then show a child fragment. From the child fragment class, I am trying to show a ListPopupWindow which needs me to specify a view for .AnchorView. Typically, when on a fragment or activity, this would be that respective view as it typically represents the full screen. However, my child fragment is just a small popup, similar to the "Start" menu in windows. If you think of that example, when I then click an option in the menu and want to display the ListPopupWindow, it does not show because I don't want to anchor it to the view of the child fragment (or the "Start" menu), I want to anchor it to my main/parent fragment so it shows where I want on the main window.

Here is what I tried but get a null reference.

```
var parentFragment = ChildFragmentManager.FindFragmentById(Resource.Id.my_parent_fragment);
var parentView = parentFragment.View;
```

Then later, I did:

```
optionsPopupWindow.AnchorView = parentView;
```

2. With this model explained above, what is the best way to send data between the child fragment and the parent? Ideally, I would like to simply set public properties and call methods between the two. Can this be done with a parent/child fragment? I understand that most things pass through the activity and from what I read, that is the preferred way. That said, I was wondering if in some cases, it is acceptable and possible to do it directly between the fragments.

Thanks!

Comment: Nested fragments are supported as of Android 4.2 (and Android Support Library rev 11) : http://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-4.2.html#NestedFragments

Comment: Correct. I should have stated that this project is targeting KK at a minimum. I also dont have a problem using support libraries. Therefore, I am certain I meet the requirements for nested fragments.

Comment: check this "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19112641/getting-a-reference-to-a-child-fragment-after-the-parent-fragment-has-been-recre"

Comment: why don't you have a view pager in another fragment of parent fragment